# Input array fuction that return more than one value

Tags: c

"Create a program that implements a function that inputs a vector and its size, returns the maximum and minimum of the vector through two parameters of the function"
I'm doing this program but I can not find the error. I'm going in the right direction?

-Sorry for my bad english.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function (int A[],int size,int *max, int *min)
{
    int temp,i,j;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;i<size;j++)
        {
            if(A[i] < A[j])
            {
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }
        }

    }

    *min = A[size]; 
    *max = A[0];

    return 0;
}



int main ()

{
    int size,i;
    int max,min;
    int *A;

    printf("Enter size of the array ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    A = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter value:");
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    }

    function(A,size,&max,&min);

    printf("The min is: %d\n",min);
    printf("The max is: %d:\n",max);

}
```

Comment: There is no need to sort the array if all you need are the maximum and minimum values.

Comment: `A[size]` is out of bounds as A is only `size` elements long.

Comment: As pointed out by OmG, the second `for` loop has the wrong test (it should test `j` not `i`). Also, you can reduce the number of iterations by using `for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)` and `for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)`. But it is still O(n^2) and you don't need to sort anyway, just search for the min and max in a single loop.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`, needed to expose the prototype for the function: `malloc()`  The posted code will also need a call to `free()` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: The posted sorting algorithm seems to be a bit 'off'  Suggest google for the 'bubble' sort or 'insertion' sort algortihm

Comment: in C, index (for instance into an array) has the range of 0...(one less than the number of entries in the array)  in this case, `size-1`.  So this statement: `*min = A[size];` is accessing past the end of the array.

Comment: the sorting algorithm your trying to implement becomes a CPU hog as the number of entries in the array exceeds (approx) 10

Comment: regarding: `for(j=0;i<size;j++)` this has some problems,  Suggest: `for (j=i; j < (size-1); j++ )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) function names should use an active verb to describe what they are doing.  For instance, rather than `function()`  suggest: `findMinMaxValuesInArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors. Please read the comments of following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function (int A[],int size,int *max, int *min) // you're not returning any value from this function. So return type should be void
{
    int temp,i,j;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(A[i] < A[j])
            {
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }
        }

    }

    *min = A[0]; //updated
    *max = A[size-1]; //updated
       //updated,no return statement

}



int main ()

{
    int size,i;
    int max,min;
    int *A;

    printf("Enter size of the array ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    A = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter value:");
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    }

    function(A,size,&max,&min);

    printf("The min is: %d\n",min);
    printf("The max is: %d:\n",max);
    return 0;

}
```

Note: Time complexity of your program is high. You can calculate minimum and maximum value more efficiently than this.Like following program's time complexity is `O(n)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void function (int A[],int size,int *max, int *min)
{
    int i;
    *min=A[0];
    *max=A[0];

    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
    {

        if(*min>A[i])
        {
            *min = A[i];
        }
        if(*max<A[i])
        {
            *max=A[i];
        }

    }

}
```

Additional Note: you can calculate maximum and minimum during taking input. Like:

```
#include <limits.h>
int main ()

{
    int size,i;
    int max=INT_MIN,min=INT_MAX;
    int *A;

    printf("Enter size of the array ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    A = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter value:");
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        if(A[i]>max)
        {
            max = A[i];
        }
        if(A[i]<min)
        {
            min = A[i];
        }
    }


    printf("The min is: %d\n",min);
    printf("The max is: %d:\n",max);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: That function will actually get min and max the wrong way round as it sorts the array in descending order.

Comment: But he is sorting his array in ascending order here.

Comment: I stand corrected! I was mislead by the double coverage of the sorting routine.

Comment: @Ian Abbott I think that was the most crucial mistake of this code!

Comment: if `*min > A[i]`, would it not stand to reason that `*max > A[i]`, therefore you can use `else if`?

Comment: But it may produce wrong answer if all the inputs are same number.

Comment: If they are all the same number, then none will be greater or less than others, so it will evaluate to false anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In this line `for(j=0;i<size;j++)` instead of `i` should be `j`. Also, instead of `int A[]` would be better `int *A`. And final point is, as mentioned in the comments you do not need sort all array as its computational complexity is `\Theta(n^2)` in your implementation. It would be better using the common methods to find `min` and `max` in `O(n)`.